# Does C# store the address of the last element in a LinkedList?

Tags: c#, linked-list

Suppode we have a linked list in C#, say

`LinkedList<int> LList = new LinkedList<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});`

A key characteristic of a linked list as a data structure is that we don't have direct access to the i-th element like we do with an array.

But when we access `LList.Last`, I assume that C# already has the address of the last element, so that it doesn't have to go through the whole list.

Is this actually the case? Where can I confirm this information?

I've tried to look in the documentation, but I couldn't find anything in this level of detail.

Comment: That's not a "feature", it's a *"consequence"* of how linked lists work.

Comment: Make no assumptions about the implementation. One implementation may keep both head and tail references, another might not. If you need to know how this particular implementation works, look at the source code. Also, `LinkedList<T>` is not part of the C# language. It's part of the .NET Base Class Library (BCL), which can be used by any language that targets .NET, not just C#.

Comment: There are only three sentences on the documentation of that property, one is explicitly answering exactly this question.  What about the documentation for it did you find confusing?

Comment: As mentioned this is an implementation detail, but you can have a look at https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/Generic/LinkedList.cs,59

Comment: As a side note, `StringBuilder` is a tail-tracked linked list, but no one ever really knows or cares about that detail. Bet *you* didn't, either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.last):

> Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation.

While it doesn't say exactly *how* it is implemented, the fast that it's an O(1) operation strongly suggests that there's a pointer directly to the last element (or at least some way to reference the last node without traversal).

The [documentation for `LinkedList` itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-7.0) states that it's a "doubly-linked list", meaning that each node has a pointer to the next and previous nodes, so a reference to the last node is trivial:

```
var lastNode = this.Head.Prev;   // this.Head points to the "first" node
```

Comment: I think a stronger hint lies in "Because the LinkedList<T> is doubly linked, each node points forward to the Next node and backward to the Previous node.". First and Last are clearly exceptions to this rule, so presumably must be explicitly identified.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't catch that the class itself states the implementation. Added that to the answer.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock From the horse's mouth https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/26ae09784c16dfa6707cd73eca2aeb00a28741d0/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/LinkedList.cs#L61 it does indeed do `head?.prev`

Comment: a "doubly-linked list" does not imply that the first node has the previous pointer set and vice versa (the next node has the last node set). It's sometimes set to NULL. Only a "double-linked circular list" treats all nodes in the same way, as they all have their previous/next pointer set.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the implementation. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-7.0) says it's a "double linked list". AFAIK to directly access the last element in a linked list you need :

- a direct reference to the last element (usually called "Tail")

OR

- a circular linked list (the previous element pointed by the first element is the last element).

Here is how it's implemented in [Microsoft .NET Reference Source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs#L22) (I'm not sure how it's done in more recent versions like .NET Core / .NET) :

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
   // This LinkedList is a doubly-Linked circular list.

   public LinkedListNode<T> Last {
        get { return head == null? null: head.prev;}
   }
}
```

In that implementation, it's a circular linked list and so you can directly access the last element in `O(1`) time.